# Parameterization of the intersection of two curves

Tags: calculus, parametric, parametrization

I have been struggling with this Calc III problem.

The intesection of two surfaces consists of two curves.$$x^2 + \frac{y^2}{2} = 1$$ $$z^2 + \frac{y^2}{2} = 1$$  Parameterize each curve in the form (vector)$$r(t)=\left\langle x(t),y(t),z(t)\right\rangle
$$

**What I have done**
$$x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}=z^2+\frac{y^2}{2}$$ $$\sqrt x = \sqrt z$$ $$z=x, z=-x$$-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$$2t^2+y^2=2$$$$y^2=2-2t^2$$ $$y=\sqrt {2-2t^2}$$

But now when I try to solve for x and z I cannot figure out how to get them in terms of t. Perhaps I am overthinking this. I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you’re overthinking. They’re ellipses, which means that you can use sine and cosine for the parametrization. There are rational parametrizations, too, but they take a little work.

Comment: You're pretty much done. Tidying things up a bit, take $r(t)=\left(t,\sqrt{2-2t^2},-t\right)$ with $t$ ranging over $[-1,1]$, for one of the curves. Your only restriction of $x$ and $z$ is that their squares are equal and smaller than $1$, therefore you take $x=t$ or $z=t$ or whatever.